# Return multiple values from a mapping in contract call

Tags: solidity, mapping

I have been stuck on this for a while, I have a mapping
`mapping (uint => bytes) idToEmail;`

A function to populate the mapping
`function addRecord(uint id, bytes email) public payable { idToEmail[id] = email; }`

I need a function to fetch multiple values for an input of multiple keys, like
`function fetchRecords(uint[] ids) returns (bytes[]) {..}`

How do I go about doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot return a dynamic array in solidity at the moment however, you can return a byte array of fixed size. Try [Solidity: Can you return dynamic arrays in a function?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17312/solidity-can-you-return-dynamic-arrays-in-a-function) for more information

Comment: Can I concatenate or serialize the elements of the dynamic array and return that as a string?

Comment: yes you can, solidity doesn't support concatenation but you can manually concatenate bytes together and return a string representation like so: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/729/how-to-concatenate-strings-in-solidity

Comment: Also, note that you can use the solidity-stringutils package to split strings : https://github.com/Arachnid/solidity-stringutils

Comment: Great! :) I'm assuming that since contract calls are inexpensive (free?) this operation should not cost anything?