# How to efficiently query custom token

Tags: solidity, web3js

I have a smart contract with a custom token which holds some data. The Token data is defined in a struct and stored in an array:

```js
struct Token {
    string text;
    uint256 value;
}

Token[] public _token;
```

On my web page I want to display all the tokens of the current user. Therefore I have a function in my smart contract which fetches all `tokenId`s of the given address. That function is really quick, but when I want to retrieve all Tokens from the `Token[]` array with the ids I get from the previous function it lasts very long! Especially if the user has many tokens...

To fetch all the tokens of the user I iterate over all `tokenId`s and perform the following request:

```js
const token= await this.tokenContract.methods._token(tokenId).call();
```

Does anybody has an idea how to speed up the retrieval?

Comment: Not sure if relevant, but this might help: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/17312/solidity-can-you-return-dynamic-arrays-in-a-function

Answer (score 0):

If you know the current number of tokens in your contract, then you can use Javascript's native asynchronous infrastructure:

```
const tokenIds = [...Array(numOfTokens).keys()];
const promises = tokenIds.map(tokenId => this.tokenContract.methods._token(tokenIds).call());
const tokens = await Promise.all(promises);
```

If you don't know the current number of tokens in your contract, then you can add in the contract a function which returns it:

```
function getNumOfTokens() public view returns (uint256) {
    return _token.length;
}
```